# How to refresh a file that was deleted locally from a remote git branch

Tags: git, github

I have deleted a file pom.xml in my local repo. When I run

```
$git fetch -v upstream
```

I get:

```
From <remote repo>:
 = [up to date]      master     -> upstream/master
```

Is there any way to force git to refresh files *that are simply missing altogether* ?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's very hard to delete a file from a repo. What I think you're really saying is that you've deleted the file at a particular revision in the repository. Your repo has the entire history available locally, so even if you never worked with a remote repository but at some point had the file committed, then you will be able to retrieve it from the local history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### git checkout

If the file exists in the index, it needs only to be checked out:

```
git checkout deletedfile
```

Example:

```
cd my/repo
rm deletedfile 
git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    deletedfile
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
git checkout deletedfile
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

To update the file to exactly match the version in the remote:

```
git checkout upstream/master deletedfile
```

Comment: i am suspicious that would pull from the master not from the remote.. but I'll try it.  Yes I just confirmed that is the case (pulls the master not the remote).

Comment: Please be careful with your git terminology, there are no pulls in the answer - what do you mean?

Comment: @javadba: your comment suggests that your "mental model" for what git does does not match how git actually works.  I recommend working your way through at least some of the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Answer (score 0):

Your `git status` should indicate the file you have deleted.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
   deleted: path/to/myfile
```

Now do `git checkout -- path/to/myfile` to get it back.